# luarocks install returned a non-zero code: 132 (installing kong)

Tags: docker, kong, luarocks

I am trying with https://github.com/d4rkstar/kong-konga-keycloak when I run sudo docker-compose up -d kong it send me:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c luarocks install --pin lua-resty-jwt' returned a non-zero code: 132
```

Watching dockerfile it contains:

```
FROM kong:2.0.4-alpine

LABEL description="Alpine + Kong 2.0.4 + kong-oidc plugin"

USER root
RUN apk update && apk add git unzip luarocks
RUN luarocks install --pin lua-resty-jwt 0.2.2-0
RUN luarocks install kong-oidc

USER kong
```

This is the output when I install manually:

```
/ # apk add luarocks
(1/2) Installing curl (7.79.1-r0)
(2/2) Installing luarocks (2.4.4-r1)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
OK: 67 MiB in 38 packages
/ # luarocks
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

My platform is: ubuntu 20 where I am running docker 20.10.10 and docker-compose 1.29.2.

2 days after

I replaced apk add luarocks by ( [How to install gdbserver package on Alpine Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186990/how-to-install-gdbserver-package-on-alpine-docker-image) )

```
RUN apk add --no-cache make
RUN apk add --no-cache linux-headers
RUN apk add --no-cache texinfo
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc
RUN apk add --no-cache g++
RUN apk add --no-cache gfortran
# install gdb
# RUN apk add --no-cache gdb
RUN mkdir gdb-build ;\
    cd gdb-build;\
    wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.11.tar.xz;\
    tar -xvf gdb-7.11.tar.xz;\
    cd gdb-7.11;\
    ./configure --prefix=/usr;\
    make;\
    make -C gdb install;\
    cd ..;\
    rm -rf gdb-build/;
```

then now I do not get error while I build.

I get the same error when I tried to migrate:
docker-compose run --rm kong kong migrations bootstrap
and kong never start, but now luarocks works fine inside container.

Thank you

Comment: You could try to build the dockerfile manually and provide more detailed error message.

Comment: I commited previous step to error. Then I logged into container and ran luaroks it returned CORE DUMP. After manually I deleted and added luarocks with apk add luaroks when I installed I did not get any error, but when I ran it a get CORE DUMP. I must to say that it is into a virtual machine with ubuntu 20. If I build into my PC with ubuntu 20 it works fine.

Comment: I added the output in my question when I install manually after build.

Comment: According to:  https://medium.com/@nprch_12/docker-exited-132-e38f9dd2cd0d I found my architecture does not support SSE4.2, and it would be the reason of my issue. Has anyone any workarround ?